# How to pass json file as a input in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am not able to pass the required Json file as a body in JMeter while automating this api. In Postman we are uploading the json file as a value to a key. I am not able to figuring out how i can pass the same in JMeter.

Can anyone please help me on the same? Please find the attached screen shot for more details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLgmU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Files Upload" in HTTP Sampler and check "Use multipart/form-data for Post" and provide the path of json, parameter name (guessing "permissions") and MIME type. Check jmeter help for more info on this.

Hope this help.

In case of any issue, try to record it in jmeter and then check the recorded sampler for more information.

Comment: @BishnuPrasad if any of the answer here that helped you than you can accept that answer and vote.This will help others also. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Configure Postman to use JMeter as the [proxy](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/proxy). The configuration lives under `File -> Settings -> Proxy`

   [image: Postman Configure Proxy]
2. Prepare JMeter for recording, the fastest way is using [JMeter Templates Feature](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building). The configuration lives under `File -> Templates -> Recording`.

   [image: JMeter Recording Template]
3. Copy your `ExpensePermissionsTemplate.json` file to JMeter's "bin" folder
4. Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click `Start` button
5. Execute your request in Postman
6. JMeter should capture the request under Thread Group -> Recording Controller

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)